# Wix Support: Create a page with wild card url

Tags: url, redirect, url-routing

I have wix website. I do want to create a page with a custom url.
So briefly I want all the url with

```
www.somedomain.com/books/*
```

to be redirect to my created wix page.
Any way possible.

Url Example:

When ever user types url such as:

```
www.somedomain.com/books/1
www.somedomain.com/books/2
www.somedomain.com/books/3
www.somedomain.com/books/4
www.somedomain.com/books/5
www.somedomain.com/books/6
```

then the redirection should be to my created page on Wix whose url is: `"www.somedomain.com/books"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant you have full control over `www.somedomain.com/books/`, you could redirect using HTML.

Go to the head tag --> add the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=YourWixSiteHere.com" />
```

if you want to make this shorter, I'm not sure how

Comment: But the concern is how Wix would know to open my created page whose url is: (www.somedomain.com/books) when user types the url as: "www.somedomain.com/books/1",  "www.somedomain.com/books/2", "www.somedomain.com/books/3"

Comment: You can set the YourWixSiteHere.com in my code manually to every web page you have.

Comment: But the url are unknown since the ids after /books denotes the record. So how we could be directing books/1, books/2 to my Wix page